# Are there two known ASCII-only strings which have the same MD5 hash value?

Tags: collision-resistance, md5

Up to now, the pairs of strings that create an MD5 collision that have been discovered all contain non-ASCII (binary) characters.

Are there two known ASCII-only strings which have the same MD5 hash value? For instance the set of characters [0-9A-Za-z]?

Comment: I started to type an answer, but it is already way too late for me here. In general, I think you need at least one block that is ASCII by chance, and since one block is 64 bytes, that would require at least somewhere in the order of $2^{64}$ operations to be found with a good chance, at the minimum. This assumes a generic attack using just two blocks that collide, where the other block is almost but not quite identical to the first one. In other words, you'd need a specialized attack, and that I could not find.